# How to determine Traffic Density of a location given LAT/LONG using GMaps or Bing Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, azure-maps

I am working on a problem which requires traffic density of a given location (e.g., a highway intersection, highway exits). Is there a way to find the traffic density given the Geographical Coordinates (LAT/LONG) of the location using the GMaps or Bing Maps API?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Maps platform has a couple of API's that might be useful;

- [Traffic flow segment API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/gettrafficflowsegment): Provides information about the speeds and travel times of the road fragment closest to the given coordinates. This API sounds pretty close, if not exactly, what you are looking for.
- [Traffic flow tile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/gettrafficflowtile): This API provides traffic flow information as map tiles. Map tiles are available in two formats; raster images (PNG) and as vector tiles. The vector tiles contains a number between 0 and 1 indicating the value of the traffic flow/density based on one of the four different trqaffic flow styles/methods it provides data for. You could calculate the tile the coordinate falls in, then snap to the closest line in the tile and extract the data you are looking for that way.